# Protecting files within folders on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a private wordpress website which is made 'private' with a plugin. Now it asks users to enter a password to view the site. However, if someone has the full link to files that are uploaded on the site, they can download them without any authentication. I managed to prevent a directory listing with .htaccess but files can still be downloaded. Is there a way to prevent downloads unless the user is logged in? Perhaps with .htaccess itself?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post - I found it really useful to do a similar thing for gravity forms uploads - http://www.mojowill.com/developer/secure-your-gravity-forms-uploads/

Comment: @McNab Thanks a ton. I'm going to try this out and see if it works!

Comment: No problem - it should address the issue you've got as it's the same issue for the Gravity Forms problem it addresses. Wordpress needs the uploads folder to be writable for resizing the images, but you have to protect them too. In my case it was because Gravity Forms was being used to upload CVs/Resumes.  If it fixes your problem then I will write a proper answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Yes it worked for my case since I have a private website that requires a login to view it and I wanted to prevent unauthenticated downloads of all uploaded files. Also, I noticed that all subdirectories get automatically protected which is, again, great in my case. However, in Wordpress you can't upload files based on their filetype. Hence it would be difficult to protect lets say only .zip files but show all image files. Which is why when I tried this out on a public website, it won't show any images under the uploads folder (I dont organize my uploads by month and year and hence no subdirs).